# What's the best way to run PHP within Rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

I'd like to run PHP from within Rails, so I'd like to be able to compile both PHP and Ruby code in the `.erb` files. I can't figure out the best way to do this, and I'm having a hard time finding information about it without becoming completely lost.

I'm currently a Rails noob and a PHP lover so I'm using WEBrick on my Mac but Apache on my server (Windows), and I'd like to use both Rails and PHP on my Apache server if that's possible. I've heard about Passenger, but I've looked in `httpd.conf` on my Windows server and there's no `mod_rails` to be found.

I don't know if I'm ready to try installing Passenger on a Windows machine. Is that even possible? What even is Passenger?

Thanks!

Comment: Might I humbly suggest that embracing Ruby would be a better strategy?

Comment: I'm not entirely new to Ruby and RoR, but I still feel like a noob.

Comment: So learn, at some point you must have been a noob at php.  If you get stuck then there are loads of people here who will help you.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do here! 

Comment: The closest thing to `mod_rails` is [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/). They even own `modrails.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's probably possible, it's a bad idea. The only time PHP should run with RoR is when it is an external source that is queried such as a PHP API that RoR consumes.

By combining PHP with Ruby on Rails, you are going against what Ruby on Rails is designed for and will make your code a lot less portable. The purpose or RoR is to make uniform code that follows the principles set by the creator. So, as Robert Harvey said, you should really truly embrace RoR. This will make your code easier to read for other developers and will also make asking questions on here and other forums easy since it would be a RoR question not a combined sudo question.

A good sign for not using PHP is that there are no obvious solutions out there for this that are pain free. From that, it's pretty apparent that there is no really need for it past making development easier for somebody switching frameworks.

So, I would suggest learning Ruby On Rails fully vs trying to combined them. It's going to take a while to learn all you need, but the same could be said about any framework/language.

NOTE: This might be a helpful resource if you need it [http://www.amazon.com/Rails-PHP-Developers-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356042](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356042)

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thank you so much for helping me. It's perfectly understandable that you'd either want to use PHP *or* RoR. Thanks, again!

Comment: Railstutorial.org is also an incredibly useful site for getting up and running quickly with RoR.